# .Net Core WebApi OAuth2 Grant Types

Tags: c#, .net-core, oauth-2.0, webapi

I have been attempting to read up on OAUTH2 as I have developed an API I am looking to secure.
I have experimented using `JWT` tokens but would like to prototype an OAuth2 implementation. The problem I am having (Besides Authentication vs Authorization) is grant_types.
My API will be used in a number of different ways

- Internal Applications (Console Apps for Integrations and Web/Desktop Based apps depending on use case).
- External Applications (Both Web and Desktop/Native Apps).

Originally I thought of using Client_Credentials. The problem here is that it works well for applications integrating with my API for migration purposes but doesn't hold the identity of a user when wanting to provide fine grained role/permission level access.

I then thought of using Authorization Code which would be great from a user perspective - and enable single sign on - but would kill the integrations as they couldn't cope with an authentication redirect (the apps will likely be services running on servers).

My last option seems to be Resource Owner Password Credentials which would work well in both scenarios yet seems frowned on in many posts I've read and is considered a serious security hole.

I have considered splitting the api up but I would prefer a single gateway.
Another consideration could be to change the grant type per client so that integrations and users are treated differently but I'm not sure.

Any help or advice this wonderful community can offer would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to setup your system to accept both `client_credential` and `Authorization Code (with PKCE)` flows.

`client_credentials` will be used when systems login.

`Authorization Code (with PKCE)` for users.

You can add scopes/claims/groups or other attributes to the token to grant access to the resource.

If you set this up correctly, both mechanisms will be working the same.

---

`Resource Owner Password Credentials` is an outdated flow and recommended against.

As [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/flows) puts it:

> Though we do not recommend it, highly-trusted applications can use the Resource Owner Password Flow, which requests that users provide credentials (username and password), typically using an interactive form.

Comment: Thanks for that Stefan - makes a lot of sense.